# error activity need to extend ReactFragmentActivity or ReactCompatActivity when app is opened from an 3rd party app

Tags: react-native, react-native-screens

I have a react-native application that is crushing if it is open from ODK Collect. It opens and works perfectly if it is open from its icon.

The error is `In order to use RNScreens components your app's activity need to extend ReactFragmentActivity or ReactCompatActivity`.

both which are deprecated. I am using react-native-screens ^3.8.0. I have tried various suggested solutions but I am not going anywhere.

Manifest:

```xml
<activity android:name=".DActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.d.odk"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

DActivity.java:

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import com.babisoft.ReactNativeLocalization.ReactNativeLocalizationPackage;
import com.facebook.react.common.LifecycleState;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.lugg.ReactNativeConfig.ReactNativeConfigPackage;
import com.oblador.keychain.KeychainPackage;
import com.reactnativecommunity.asyncstorage.AsyncStoragePackage;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedPackage;
import com.swmansion.rnscreens.RNScreensPackage;
import com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext.SafeAreaContextPackage;


public class DActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {

    private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //tried null as well
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    Bundle initialProps = new Bundle();
    initialProps.putString("AppCaller", "Denes");

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
      .setApplication(getApplication())
      .setCurrentActivity(this)
      .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
      .setJSMainModulePath("index")
      .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
      .addPackage(new KeychainPackage())
      .addPackage(new AsyncStoragePackage())
      .addPackage(new ReactNativeConfigPackage())
      .addPackage(new ReactNativeLocalizationPackage())
      .addPackage(new ReanimatedPackage())
      .addPackage(new RNScreensPackage())
      .addPackage(new SafeAreaContextPackage())
      .addPackage(new RNGestureHandlerPackage())
      .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
      .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
      .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "app", initialProps);
    setContentView(mReactRootView);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    
        if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
            mReactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this);
        }
        if (mReactRootView != null) {
            mReactRootView.unmountReactApplication();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?